# Updating Azure Cloud Service to OS family 7

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services, windows-server-2019, azure-sdk-.net

I am using Azure DevOps to deploy a .Net Application. I wanted to update to the new OS Family 7 which is based on Windows Server 2022. I have updated my cloud service configuration '.cscfg' file to osFamily="7" but when I try to deploy the app even though the Build succeeds I get this error when I try to deploy:

> message: "The operation '2b1cdaa09ef40122944b9c73b91c78cc' failed: 'The OS family 7 you are trying to deploy is not supported by the SDK package. The SDK package supported OS families:3,4,5,6,1,2,98,97. Please try to deploy to a different operating system. To do this specify a different osFamily and/or osVersion in your .cscfg file.

I currently have Azure .NET SDK v2.9 Installed.
I am currently using OS based on Windows Server 2019 (OS: WAOSWS19G230908-2236)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you shared, the reason of the issue is that the current Azure SDK doesn't support OS Family 7.

If you are using Microsoft-hosted agent, please try to use the latest image `windows-2022` to deploy.

If you are using a self-hosted agent, you can try to install the latest Azure SDK on your local machine and deploy again.